# return incorrect count on activerecords

Tags: activerecord, yii

I'm trying to count the number of records. We have looked at it for days, and the count isn't correct. It keeps returning 1 when there's nothing. All the other models' count return correctly, so this one is quite bizzare. Any other places I need to check?

Things already looked at:

1. var_dump: so it returns 0; everything as expected;
2. check scope if there's some kind of conflict;

`$pending = count(Model::model()->pending());`

Rules are safe in model. Model:

```
public function pending()
    {
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

        $now = new CDbExpression("NOW()");
        $criteria->addCondition('effective_to_date > '.$now);
        $criteria->addCondition('effective_from_date < '.$now);
        $criteria->compare('target_accept',"ACCEPTED");

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(   'criteria'=>$criteria,  ));
    }
```

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataProvider#itemCount-detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is that you are returning `CActiveDataProvider` instance which itself does not contain the data rather you can get list of objects using method getData().

You can write like this

```
public function pending()
    {
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

        $now = new CDbExpression("NOW()");
        $criteria->addCondition('effective_to_date > '.$now);
        $criteria->addCondition('effective_from_date < '.$now);
        $criteria->compare('target_accept',"ACCEPTED");
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(   'criteria'=>$criteria,  ));
        return $dataProvider->getData();
    }
```

Also you can use property `totalItemCount` like `$dataProvider->totalItemCount` to get total count of records. and then you can directly use this count in your lvalue like

```
$pending=Model::model()->pending()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
$dp = Model::model()->pending();
echo count($dp->getData())
```